# JPA/Hibernate pagination - bad COUNT query for @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) with @Where

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can someone please help me?
I am trying to use the spring data JPA with a soft delete using the where clause in an inherited class. However, it seems that is not considering the inheritance when Pageable class generates its query to count the number of rows.

ClassA class (Base class): <- the deleted column is here

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "SYS_ELEMENT") 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 63) @DiscriminatorValue("Element") 
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE SYS_ELEMENT SET DELETED = 1, DELETED_ID = ID, DELETED_VERSION = VERSION WHERE ID = ? AND VERSION = ? ", check = ResultCheckStyle.COUNT) 
@Where(clause="DELETED = 0" ) 
public class Element extends EntityBase  { 
}
```

ClassB class (Inherited class):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SYS_FORM")
@DiscriminatorValue("Form")
public class Form extends Element {
}
```

I load the following code:

```
 Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
 Page page = service.findByAll(pageable);
```

And that is my exception:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* select
        count(generatedAlias0) 
    from
        Form as generatedAlias0 */ select
            count(form0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
        from
            sys_form form0_ 
        where
            (
                form0_1_.DELETED = 0
            )
2020-07-09 21:23:10.123  WARN 22464 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 4104, SQLState: S0001
2020-07-09 21:23:10.123 ERROR 22464 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The multi-part identifier "form0_1_.DELETED" could not be bound.
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@748df19a
```

If I remove the where clause, it works.
I am not sure it is a spring data JPA or JPA issue.

As requested, here is a simple example:

- https://github.com/caiquebispoferreira/springdatajpa
- https://github.com/gtiwari333/hibernate-inheritance-JOINED-with-where-bug
  (simpler example)

Comment: can you create a small project and put on github so that it will be easy for us to reproduce and investigate?

Comment: Sure, i just updated my post with my github link (https://github.com/caiquebispoferreira/springdatajpa)

Comment: Thanks, I noticed only the count query is not generating properly(as you posted above) but the select query is fine. Must be some issue with Hibernate  since ``org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery#doList`` method and friends generate the query and execute.

Comment: @gtiwari333 I noticed it as well. Do you know how to proceed in this case? Can we open an issue?

Comment: I will dig into the hibernate test cases on GitHub and try to reproduce it over there. We might need to verify if its actually a bug and we are not doing anything differently before opening an issue . I  will work on this later tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: That's fantastic. If you need any forward action, please let me know.

Comment: @gtiwari333 do you have any feedback?

Comment: Yes, i did some testing and digging and found that its only an issue with @Inheritance strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED. It appears its an issue with hibernate version >  5.4.4.Final. So, if  ``you use hibernate.version = 5.4.4.Final you won't get the error``. I also created a sample project based on your project to reproduce the bug. https://github.com/gtiwari333/hibernate-inheritance-JOINED-with-where-bug

Comment: Also its related the bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13712?jql=text%20~%20%22Inheritance%20count%20where%22 (now closed). It seems we do not have ability to create tickets over there

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14112  I opened a new ticket for this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Hibernate.

You can try an old hibernate version **5.4.4.Final** now or wait until **5.4.19** is released. Watch for the following items for the release date.

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14112
- https://in.relation.to/hibernate-orm/

Comment: I am going to be using the old hibernate version 5.4.4.Final now while I wait for 5.4.19.

Comment: 5.4.19 is released today :)