# JPA/Hibernate: invalid COUNT query alias for JOINED inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring boot 2.3.12.RELEASE and Hibernate 5.4.32.Final. I'm using JOINED inheritance strategy for several classes with parent entity mapped like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dos_t_requests")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Request {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sq_requests")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sq_requests", sequenceName = "dos_sq_requests", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "req_num")
    private String number;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @Column(name = "edited_at")
    private LocalDateTime editedAt;

    @Column(name = "executed_at")
    private LocalDateTime executedAt;

    @Column(name = "issued_at")
    private LocalDateTime issuedAt;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    ...
}
```

And here is one of child entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dos_t_stud_reqs")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class StudentRequest extends Request {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stud_id")
    private Student student;

    ...
}
```

I need to count the total number of rows of child entities to paginate the results. So I have a method that does all the work:

```
public Page<RequestPartInfo> getAll(DbUser dbUser, int page, int pageSize) {
    
    ...

    String cntQuery;
    String entQuery;
    if (dbUser.getDbType() == DbUserType.STUDENT) {
        cntQuery = String.join("\n",
            "select count(r.id)",
            "from StudentRequest r",
            "where r.student.id = :userId");
        entQuery = String.join("\n",
            "from StudentRequest r",
            "join fetch r.document d",
            "join fetch d.recipient rc",
            "join fetch r.curator c",
            "join fetch r.executor e",
            "join fetch r.issueType it",
            "join fetch r.status st",
            "where r.student.id = :userId",
            "order by r.createdAt desc");
    }

    ...
        
    long count = em.createQuery(cntQuery, Long.class).setParameter("userId", dbUser.getId()).getSingleResult();
    List<RequestPartInfo> requests = em.createQuery(entQuery, Request.class).setParameter("userId", dbUser.getId())
        .setFirstResult(page * pageSize).setMaxResults(pageSize).getResultList()
            .stream().map(this::mapPartInfo).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return PagingUtil.createPage(requests, page, pageSize, count);
}
```

When I call this method, Hibernate generates an incorrect database query:
`select count(studentreq0_.id) as col_0_0_ from oksana.dos_t_stud_reqs studentreq0_ where studentreq0_.id=studentreq0_1_.id and studentreq0_.stud_id=?`
The problem with this request is that the WHERE section uses an alias that is not present in the FROM section. So I get following error: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "STUDENTREQ0_1_"."ID": invalid identifier`.

I tried to search for a solution to the problem on the internet and found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826016/jpa-hibernate-pagination-bad-count-query-for-inheritancestrategy-inheritan). But it says that this bug has been fixed in Hibernate 5.4.19.

Comment: try removing @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")

Comment: @grigouille, already tried, no difference.

Comment: try "select count(r) from StudentRequest r where r.student.id = :userId"

Comment: @grigouille, same error unfortunately.