# Hibernate Jpa generating wrong table alias inheritance joined

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using **Hibernate.6.2.5.Final** and **jpa:3.1.1** with **postgres 9.6**

There is a problem while generating the sql query for this named query that I declared in the jpa repository.

```
boolean existsPeriodicByIsbnAndTitle(@Param("isbn") String isbn, @Param("title") String title);
```

Spring is generating this sql and error:

```
JDBC exception executing SQL [select p1_0.idperiodic from periodic p1_0 where p1_1.isbn=? and p1_0.title=? fetch first ? rows only] [ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "p1_1"
```

As you can see is trying to use an alias on the isbn field *p1_1* that has not been declared.

Here are my class definitions:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
@ToString(of = {"id", "group"})
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPublication {

    @Id
    @OrderBy
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "publication_id_sequence")
    private Long id;

    ....

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = Book.BOOK_TABLE_NAME)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = Book.BOOK_TYPE_COLUMN, discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "publication_id_sequence", sequenceName = "book_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Book extends AbstractPublication {


    @Column(name = "ISBN", length = 50)
    private String isbn;

    ....
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@DiscriminatorOptions(force = true)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "PERIODIC")
@Table(name = "PERIODIC")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDPERIODIC")
public class Periodic extends Book {

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    ...
}
```

I believe the error comes from the **inheritence type JOINED** between the class Book and the class Periodic. Hibernate knows he can't find the isbn in the Periodic table and then use a new alias, except that it forgets to JOIN with the table book.

I appreciate your help with this issue even though it seems more like an hibernate jpa internal problem.

(Update) Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
    id 'java'
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "9.16.3"
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application.
    id 'application'
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.1"
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'xxxx'
sourceCompatibility = 17

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    springBatchVersion = "5.0.1"
    testContainersVersion = "1.18.0"
    lombokVersion = '1.18.26'
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:24.0.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
    implementation("org.springframework:spring-context-support")

    //http client 5 required
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5:5.2.1'

    // spring-batch
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch") {
        exclude(module: 'spring-batch-infrastructure')
    }
    implementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:${springBatchVersion}")

    // Logger
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.6")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.6")

    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.23.0")

    // Json
    implementation("org.json:json:20230227")
    implementation("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.8.0")
    implementation("io.rest-assured:json-schema-validator:5.3.0")

    // Freemarker ftlh templates
    implementation('org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.32')

    //HTMl XML parser
    implementation("org.jsoup:jsoup:1.15.4")
    implementation("net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.27")

    //PDF Creator
    implementation("org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-itext5:9.1.22")
    implementation('org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.28')

    implementation("net.sf.saxon:Saxon-HE:12.1") {
        exclude group: "net.sf.saxon", module: "xpath"
    }

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.lookfirst/sardine
    implementation('com.github.lookfirst:sardine:5.10')

    //JACKSON LIBRARY
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-parameter-names', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-guava', version: '2.14.2'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'classmate', version: '1.5.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.16.1' // needed for safe html annotation

    // apache commons
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.10.0")
    implementation("commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4")
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.10.0'

    //google
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre'

    //apache excel
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.23.0'

    //openapi
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0")

    // Lombok
    annotationProcessor('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:3.0.5',
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    compileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    testAnnotationProcessor("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")
    testCompileOnly("org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}")

    testImplementation("org.dbunit:dbunit:2.6.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test")

    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0")

    //Mockito
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.2.0'
    // testContainers
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:${testContainersVersion}")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql:${testContainersVersion}")
}

// Apply a specific Java toolchain to ease working on different environments.
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'xxxx.Application'
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['--add-opens', 'java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED',
                                 '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED',
                                 '--add-opens', 'java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED']
}

tasks.register('copyResources', Copy) {
    from "upload"
    into "$buildDir/upload"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

There are similar questions but it was on hibernate 5.4.4 and I'm using the latest one:

[JPA/Hibernate: invalid COUNT query alias for JOINED inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078260/jpa-hibernate-invalid-count-query-alias-for-joined-inheritance)
[JPA/Hibernate pagination - bad COUNT query for @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED) with @Where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62826016/jpa-hibernate-pagination-bad-count-query-for-inheritancestrategy-inheritan)

Comment: I tried your code with jpa with Postgres and jpa with mysql and it is generating the correct joined query. Can you please share your pom.xml as well?

Comment: Thanks for trying @rahulP, I posted my dependencies file. There is also another detail that I didn't post before (now its available) about the classes definition, it's a 3 class dependency AbstractPublication -> Book -> Periodic

Comment: I can confirm this is an hibernate problem I downgraded to org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final and it works perfectly as expected.